# Актуальность WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Подскажите, актуален ли сейчас WPF, как фреймворк для написания настольных приложений или есть что-то более стильное, модное и молодежное?

Наткнулся на какой-то Avalonia, который долгое время находится в разработке. Как я понимаю- это убийца WPF? И как я понимаю- это тот же WPF, но с плюхами и кроссплатформой?

Comment: "Avalonia is currently in beta". А скачать и проверить его в работе для того, чем конкретно хотели бы заниматься вы - вам никто не запрещает. Бывает, что и вполне stable проект таков, что пользоваться им добровольно не захочешь. Актуальным же для написания приложений под Windows на C# пока остается WPF, а не что-либо стороннее и даже не UWP. Другой вопрос - само написание приложений под Windows уже не так уж актуально.

Comment: Если вы пишете только для Wndows и именно десктоп приложение, то WPF -  это именно то, что вам нужно

Comment: В Авалонии пока нет грида и есть проблемы с производительностью. Зато оно кроссплатформенное, особенно на netCore.

Comment: Сейчас в Avalonia уже есть DataGrid. Это для тех, кто будет в будущем читать.